# ng-scrollbar issue with md-sidenav in angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using **mailhu custom scrollbar plugin** together with **ngScrollbar**.

It works fine with `<md-content>` but I'm facing issues with `<md-sidenav>`

After execution of this code

```
<md-sidenav md-swipe-left="sidenav_toggle()"
            class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2"
            md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')"
            md-component-id="leftNav"
            md-scroll-y
            ng-scrollbars
            ng-scrollbars-config="vertScrollConfig">

      ...
</md-sidenav>
```

with vertScrollConfig as -

```
$scope.vertScrollConfig = {
                    autoHideScrollbar: false,
                    theme: 'minimal-dark',
                    advanced:{
                        updateOnContentResize: true
                    },
                    axis: 'y',
                    scrollInertia: 400,
                };
```

I receive following **$compile:multidir** error -

[image: $compile:multidir error]

Found some stuff at [Angular Site](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$compile/multidir?p0=mdSidenav&p1=%20(module%3A%20material.components.sidenav)&p2=ngScrollbars&p3=%20(module%3A%20ngScrollbars)&p4=new%2Fisolated%20scope&p5=%3Cmd-sidenav%20md-swipe-left%3D%22sidenav_toggle()%22%20class%3D%22md-sidenav-left%20md-whiteframe-z2%20_md-closed%22%20md-is-locked-open%3D%22%24mdMedia(%27gt-sm%27)%22%20md-component-id%3D%22leftNav%22%20ng-scrollbars%3D%22%22%20ng-scrollbars-config%3D%22vertScrollConfig%22%20tabindex%3D%22-1%22%3E) but I didn't understand what to do actually and which is the directive emerging the issue.

Please do respond as detailed as possible as I'm a beginner at this angular stuff.

Comment: The error you are getting is this - https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir (which you can get to by clicking on the error in the console). Looks like `ng-scrollbars` directives cause a problem with `md-sidenav`. I'm curious, why do you need to use `ng-scrollbars`? What does it do that you can't achieve with Angular Material?

Comment: I have to **replace the regular scrollbar of Left Side Nav to Malihu Scrolbar**, and as specified in its documentation, I need to specify `ng-scrollbars` to the component to change its scrollbar style

Answer (score 0):

Found a temporary fix..!

```
<script>
        $('md-sidenav').mCustomScrollbar({
              axis: "y",
              autoExpandScrollbar: false,
              autoHideScrollbar: false,
              theme: 'dark',
              advanced:{
                     updateOnContentResize: true
              },
              scrollButtons: {
                     scrollAmount: 'auto', 
                     enable: true 
              },
        });
</script>
```

**But thats not fine, need to fix this issue or so called bug.**